# Can a MQTT client publish multiple messages concurrently to a Broker?

Tags: concurrency, mqtt, messaging

I am trying to set up an MQTT messaging system in which I have the following constraint:

I have a client that wants to send different types of messages, each to a type specific topic. For example, one type is a short message describing only a state the client is in, another type is a file that can sometimes be quite large.

The point is that I would like the client to be able to send messages simultaneously: since the connection speed may be limited, if it publishes a large message containing a large file, and right after that, a message containing a state, I would like the state to be sent in parallel, so that the long file does not block the short state message.

In a nutshell, the messages sent to the same topic would all be sent one after the other, but I would like to be able to parallelize the sending across different topics.

Also, the system topology would require bridges between multiple brokers. If it is possible between a client and a broker, will parallelization of sending between multiple brokers also be possible?

I've already tried with Mosquitto Brokers and Paho Clients on Python by creating multiple Threads with one Client each, but even that doesn't seem to make parallelization possible. I'm still open on the choice of client and language for the implementation.

In the hope of not having been too long and of having summarized the subject simply enough, thanks to those who have already read this far!

Answer (score 0):

No, a client has a single TCP connection to the broker and messages need to be sent in a single stream of bytes, you can not multiplex multiple messages at the same time on the stream.

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this by using different clients for each type of message? Sorry if my questions sound stupid, but I'm not a networking pro. I am also a bit concerned about finding nothing on the subject over forums and the official documentation.

Comment: How multiple clients will behave will depend on the broker they are connected to. e.g. mosquitto is built round a single threaded event loop, so it can only receive one message at a time from all connected clients.

Comment: Okay, thanks for your explainations. 
For you to know, by experimenting, I saw that we are able to setup multiple bridges between 2 brokers, so that what I wanted is possible : bridge_1 syncs topic_group_1 and bridge_2 topic_group_2, and I am now able to multiplex my sendings !

Is it because one bridge establishes a loop of events in a single thread that the second also works in parallel?

Comment: Bridges don't help you, because the bridge traffic between the brokers is handled on the same event loop as any other client.

Comment: If so, I don't understand why I am currently able to send a first message with a large payload through one bridge (with a slowed network speed), and then a small message through the other bridge, and the small message callback arrives first..

Actually, maybe the broker will handle each message at once, but as my clients and brokers are connected in local networks, and only bridges have limited internet speed, this solution seems to be correct for me, no?

Comment: Delivery callbacks are just that, they are called once the message has arrived at the broker it was sent to, nothing more (there is no end to end delivery notification in MQTT). So it will depend which broker the subscribing client is connected to what order the messages will be delivered. But this is the last update I will make to this question, Stack Overflow is not the place for a discussion.